# How to remove variables posted into URL adress

Tags: javascript, url

I have simple form, that posted into URL some variables like this:

http://127.0.0.1/responsiveweb/travel.php?actual_position=Berlin&final_position=Praha

How can I remove the values of these variables from url link after I click on a delete button?

Comment: I've updated the grammar and formatting of the post, and removed the extraneous (and deprecated) [delete](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/delete) tag. You may want to update your question with more specifics, like any code you've written to address this, what you've found that has worked, and what hasn't, etc. See [ask] for more information about asking a good question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = "http://127.0.0.1/responsiveweb/travel.php?actual_position=Berlin&final_position=Praha";

url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));

alert(url);
```

You can use substring to just get the beginning of the string that represents the URL.